# AngularJS directive templateUrl

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am challenged to AngularJS that but does not work occurred. 
I've created a code that uses the directive. 
However, when you use the templateUrl, it does not do what we want to do the operation. 
In my code, I am assuming that the  tag is replaced by the contents of header.html. However, you can not. 
Please lend your wisdom.

sample.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var directiveApp = angular.module('dApp', []);
directiveApp.directive('header', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "header.html",
    };
}]);
</script>

<body ng-app="dApp">
    <header></header>
</body>
```

header.html

```
<label>Hello!</label>
```

Comment: if the question is how to make the template replace the `<header>` tag just use `replace:true,` in directive  http://plnkr.co/edit/JtaCkcp8K5D1rTgKk57S?p=preview

Comment: I tried your way. But, `Error: [$ compile: tpload] http:? //errors.angularjs.org/1.3.1/$compile/tpload P0 = header.html` occurs.

Comment: I was sure operate using the IE11. In that case, it seems this error occurs locally. The source code is stored in the Web server, it seems no problem when you access. Or does not have those who know how to run as a local file?

Answer (score 0):

With templateUrl in directive, angular will send a http request to retrieve this html from you server side. So you should make sure there is such 'header.html' file in the correct url.

However, if you don't want to load this template with a ajax.  Then you can use the template in angular.

Add this to your sample.html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="header.html">
    <label>Hello!</label>
</script>
```

Hope this work for you.